# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor}{2^i} \geq n$ is untrue?

Tags: calculus

Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor}{2^i} = 2^{\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor + 1} - 1 \geq n$$ is not true for *any* $n$?

Is not that you can simply give a counter example. However, I am interested in show, algebraically if you will, that this is generally not true for any n.

Comment: Hint, there is an explicit formula for $\sum_{i=1}^m 2^i$.

Comment: I know it is a geometric series but I do not know how to use the formula to show that the inequality is not true for all n. edit: updated question to reflect that :)

Comment: I really do not know. Trust me, I have spent plenty of time on this. It would be neat if someone could post the answer´and that I could check it and maybe ask questions if I do not get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is false as stated. Let $d(n)=\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$; then $2^d(n)\le n<2^{d(n)+1}$, and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{d(n)}2^i=\frac{2^{d(n)+1}-2}{2-1}=2^{d(n)+1}-2\;.$$

Thus, you want to show that $2^{d(n)+1}-2<n$. This is clearly true iff $n=2^{d(n)+1}-1$ (since $n<2^{d(n)+1}$), so it is **not** always true.

For example, if $n\in\{4,5,6\}$, then $d(n)=2$, and $\sum_{i=1}^22^i=6\ge n$.

What **is** always true is that

$$\sum_{i=\color{red}0}^{d(n)}2^i=2^{d(n)+1}-\color{red}1\ge n\;.$$

Comment: Oh yes, simply perfect answer. I completely get it, thanks!

Comment: @overso: You’re welcome!